# Find $\gcd(10^6\cdot6^2\cdot5^{11},6\cdot15\cdot3^7)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find $\gcd(10^6\cdot6^2\cdot5^{11},6\cdot15\cdot3^7)$
>   Obtain a single number.

Attempt:

$2^8\cdot3^2\cdot5^{17},2\cdot3^9\cdot5$

So what's the GCD?

Comment: You're almost there. Which exponents for the prime factors do you need to pick for the $\gcd$?

Comment: To get multiplication dots, use \cdot, which gives $\cdot$

Comment: @user109886 Your question is badly typeset.  Could you please edit it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greatest Common Divisor.

Take *minimum* of the powers for each prime, yielding now
$$2^1\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^{1}\,.$$